# Failed to update Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying update my VS code but when I click on update it is showing an error stating "Updates may fail due to ant-virus software and/or runaway processes. Please try restarting your machine before attempting to update again. Please read the log file for more information:" and it has a log file extension which I'm unable to find and I tried restarting and then updating, but still didn't work. So please guide me as to what I should in order to update the VS code. I have an antivirus, is that causing a stoppage to the update of the IDE VS Code.

Moved the question to superuser.com as suggested by j08691.

Comment: What log file extension? Where did you look for the logs? I'm guessing that'll tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly caused by your antivirus not liking the VS Code installation.
One known example of such an antivirus is SentinelOne.

You would need to disable the antivirus while you are installing VS code,
but there is no guarantee that it will not later on decide to remove some file
of VS Code.

If you are not obliged to use this antivirus, perhaps you should change to
another one. For example, if you are on Windows, then Windows Defender is
pretty good, and it will never conflict with VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

it certainly has nothing to do with process or antivirus, I will bring a solution that works both on insiders and on standard Vscode
Copy Code.exe(vscode) or insiders.exe(if you use insiders)
After copying paste into: "C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code"
If you have trouble finding it, try looking at C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code In a folder named "_", After this process just restart your Vscode,

Hope this helps
Brazilian going